# Mantis cannot connect to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2012, mantis

I am trying to install Mantis 2.5.1 with PHP 7.0.15 and MS SQL Server 2012. The database is already created and user has db owner permission. Pre-installation check has no errors, but when I try to install database, I get an error as:

> SQLState: 08001 Error Code: 67 Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for
>   SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server [67]. ....A network-related or instance-specific error has
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not
>   found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. ...

I have checked the following already:

- Named pipes is already enabled on sql server.
- I have copied php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll to php extension directory, and enabled them as extensions in PHP manager in IIS 7.
- Connection to sql server is possible with same credentials (tested using conn.udl)

**Settings in config_defaults_inc.php**

```
$g_hostname = 'Driver={SQLServer};SERVER=server;DATABASE=dbname;UID=username;PWD=password;';

$g_db_username = 'username';

$g_db_password = 'password';

$g_db_type = 'odbc_mssql';
```

What could I be missing? Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

ensure that your instance is configured for SQL Server authentication.

[image]

If you change the auth mode, you need to restart the instance, which can be done in SSMS by right click to the instance name --> restart.

Comment: Both modes are already enabled. As I mentioned, I can connect to sql server with same credentials when I try using conn.udl. I even tried the following php code in the same directory, and it shows connection established.


 $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$myDB, "UID" => $myUser, "PWD" => $myPass);
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

 if( $conn ) {
  echo "Connection established.<br />";
 }else{
  echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }

Comment: sorry i overlooked that by mistake